# Pandas remove duplicated rows by multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from my df, I want to delete the rows as follows: for each `ID` check if at least one time `COD1` = `COD2` and if `GRADE` contains the string `'A'` or `'C'`. IF this 2 condions are meet remove the rows.

My idea was to put my conditions like this:

```
indexNames = df[ (df[df.COD1 == df.COD2]) & (df[df['Grade'].isin(['A','C'])]) ].index
```

and then do the drop with

```
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

However for the first line I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'` .

I would really appreciate any idea on how to achieve my goal.
my df:

```
# -- create a dataframe 
list_columns = ['ID', 'COD1', 'COD2','Grade','Data']
list_data = [
    [3215575, 'A21', 'A21','A','2020-09-16 13:25:00'],
    [3215575, 'A11', 'A21','D','2020-09-16 13:55:00'],
    [3215575, 'A21', 'A21','E','2020-09-16 13:12:00'],
    [4058770, 'D10', '213','E','2020-09-16 12:25:00'],
    [4058770, '313', '313','E','2020-09-16 10:25:00'],
    [4058770, '313', '125','B','2020-09-16 13:19:00'],
    [4058771, 'C55', 'C55','C','2020-09-16 14:25:00'],
    [3215577, 'A21', 'A21','B','2020-09-16 13:25:00'],
    [3215577, 'A01', 'A21','D','2020-09-16 13:55:00']
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
```

Expected output:

```
    list_columns = ['ID', 'COD1', 'COD2','Grade','Data']
    list_data = [
        [4058770, 'D10', '213','E','2020-09-16 12:25:00'],
        [4058770, '313', '313','E','2020-09-16 10:25:00'],
        [3215577, 'A21', 'A21','B','2020-09-16 13:25:00'],
        [3215577, 'A01', 'A21','D','2020-09-16 13:55:00']
        ]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, ,you need a condition, with groupby and transform with any , then invert:

```
cond = (df.COD1 == df.COD2) & df['Grade'].isin(['A','C'])
df2 = df[~cond.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
        ID COD1 COD2 Grade                 Data
0  4058770  D10  213     E  2020-09-16 12:25:00
1  4058770  313  313     E  2020-09-16 10:25:00
2  4058770  313  125     B  2020-09-16 13:19:00
3  3215577  A21  A21     B  2020-09-16 13:25:00
4  3215577  A01  A21     D  2020-09-16 13:55:00
```